# X3 Albion Prelude custom game start

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

In Albion Prelude does the custom game start give you neutral reputation with all races. even the terrans, like it did in Terran Conflict?

Comment: its pretty easy to earn a positive relationship with the Terrans as long as you don't start with the argon patriot start.  And as long as its not the custom start, you won't be locked out of any of the missions (you just have to earn some rep first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That said, it also marks your game as modified (disabling achievements if you're using Steam) as well as locking you out of the possibility to do any of the mission plotlines...though there is only really one mission plotline in AP.

Comment: are you sure a custom game marks your game as modified?

Comment: Going on egosoft forum-banter here, haven't tried myself, but it was that way in x3tc, and since AP is basically a zealous mod pack for TC, it would make sense.